# Realtime datatable with asp.net core web app , EF core and SignalR

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, signalr

I want to retrieve data from Sqlserver database with EntityFramework core and do crud operations and show data table to client without refreshing the page (Realtime) , is there any source or example in this case ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure there is a definitive source for this, but it's not that hard to build yourself.

It should be relatively straight forward. In general you'd need

1. A model for the grid that defines the properties to show and edit, and also which row is selected.
2. An HTML Helper to change the rows from read-only to editable
3. A view to display the table.

An [edit] action link for each row enables you to select a row by ID for editing, and after clicking it, reloads the page and then the view can respond accordingly to change the type of the row from read-only to editable.

You could use Blazor or maybe Ajax to change a row from read-only to editable without refreshing the page, but I'm not sure if you need to meet certain requirements that discard using either of them.

John Ciliberti has written a recipe for a book, that works just like I described, find it on his [Github](https://github.com/johnciliberti/AspNetCoreRecipes/tree/master/Chapter08/Recipe06/Recipe06) page to get some ideas of what's involve.

[image]

If you need a more out-of-the-box solution, perhaps consider wiring up [DataTables.js](https://editor.datatables.net/).

[image]